# HTTP Request does not set Content Length

Tags: objective-c, ipad, http, http-headers

I'm trying to use Google Data API to upload a CSV file with some places.

I've this piece of code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:direccion]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:direccion]];

NSData *postData = [creacionCSV dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"2.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
[request setValue:@"application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"Mapa de prueba" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Slug"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *datosRecibidos;
datosRecibidos = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *token = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:datosRecibidos encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",token);
```

Where creacionCSV is an NSString with all the KML code.
Once executed, I've obtained this answe from server:

```
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Error 411 (Length Required)!!1</title>
  <style> [...] </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/ id=g><img src=//www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif alt=Google></a>
  <p><b>411.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.  
  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

So I'm getting that 411 Error. I've checked the header and it's not nil nor empty. Why is not taking that header my POST?

Many thanks!

Comment: If I set a breakpoint at the last line, I can see that self.tokenAutorizacion is not nil nor empty but if I print object for [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"] it's a nil one. That's my problem. I don't know why my request does not take any Authorization HTTP header

Comment: For synchronous requests: `If authentication is required in order to download the request, the required credentials must be specified as part of the URL. If authentication fails, or credentials are missing, the connection will attempt to continue without credentials.`

Comment: It worked for me that way. I've added at the end of the URL &token=MY_TOKEN and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I'm now having problems with [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
It seems to be ok but once the POST request is done, I got this answer from server: Error 411 (Length Required)

Answer (score 0):

How do you build tokenAutorizacion, the base64 encoding? See this page: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html